# Hyperlink of several lines

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have several lines that I need to be a link all together. I wrote this code. It is considered as a link by the browser but it is not clickable?
Am I doing this wrong?

```html
<div class="padding-title">

  <a herf="index.html">

    <p class="small"><font face="courier" size="4">
          <h1>line1</h1>
          </font>
    </p>

    <p class="small2"><font face="courier" size="4">
           line2<br>
           line3<br>
           line4
           </font>
    </p>

  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the `a` tag should wrap the `p` tags if you want them all to link to one place.

But you misspelled the `a` tag's "href" attribute and wrote "herf" instead. Make sure you read your code!

Comment: OMG i am such an idiot. Thanks Elliott. it's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

1st `<font>` is **deprecated**, so **don't** use it, then to make the `a` clickable you need the `href`, which you have it but with a typo.

```html
<div class="padding-title">
  <a href="index.html">
    <h1>line1</h1>
    <p class="small2">
      line2
      <br />line3
      <br />line4
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dippas. i get it.

Comment: If this fixed your issue make sure you mark the answer as accepted (or at least upvote it since was useful to you and can be to others in the future)